# Smoothening a normal/gaussian plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, gaussian, normal-distribution

I have a numpy array of numbers (floats).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

mean=np.mean(array1)
sigma=np.std(array1)    
plt.plot(array1,mlab.normpdf(array1,mean,sigma))
plt.show()
```

What I get is the following:[image]

Is there a way to smoothen out the distribution?

Comment: How do you get `array1`?

Comment: Its from a file. Actually I think they used a technique (trying to reproduce a plot in a journal) called kernel density regression.

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact code that you're using to plot it? You're not filling anything at all?

Comment: Yes, not filling it at all. I think the error is the original authors used kernel density regression to smoothen array1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your array with the following code. `a` is your array.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

a = np.random.randn(500)*5
plt.plot(a, mlab.normpdf(a, np.mean(a), np.std(a)))
plt.show()
```

Which leads to this abomination:
[image: Bad example]

One solution is to just sort the data array. `n` is the normal probability density function based on `a`. `np.argsort` returns the indices of `a` with which you can sort `a` and `n`.

```
n = mlab.normpdf(a, np.mean(a), np.std(a))
ind = np.argsort(a)
a = a[ind]
n = n[ind]
plt.plot(a,n)
plt.show()
```

[image: Better Plot.]

This is - of course - not [smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing#Smoothing_algorithms) in the real sense. But I think this may solve your problem. You also could just do a plot with markers instead of lines:

```
plt.plot(a, mlab.normpdf(a, np.mean(a), np.std(a)), 'o')
```

which also will result in a more 'practical' plot.